# Add two or more domains to one public IP using A records

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, domain-name, a-record

I have a public IP address that houses two applications e.g 197.18.2.48 houses 192.18.2.48/systems and 192.18.2.48/shop , I would like to map this two applications to my domain so that it reads

```
192.18.2.48/systems  -> systems.harris-dindi.com 
192.18.2.48/shop -> shop.harris-dindi.com
```

So the two systems with IP on the  left  should point to the subdomains on the right. I have tried using A records from the cpanel but it only accepts the  IP Address. 
Please advise

Comment: Should the A Records be for websites or what is this application? Please describe your Problem better, so we can help you better.

Comment: A website or a web application any which I would like it to run under a sub domain

Comment: Do you use apache for that? When yes use for that VirtualHosts here is an link how to create Virtualhosts. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: The local path does not belong in the DNS config - it's part of the webserver configuration. DNS tells your users which server the (sub)domain lives at, and then you configure your webserver to use the proper path for each domain name. See http://serverfault.com/a/520201/120438 for a fuller explanation.

Answer (score 2):

CPanel is correct. DNS A records resolve names to IP addresses, not to applications. What you can do is add two A records pointing to the same IP address, like so:

```
systems.harris-dindi.com. IN A 192.18.2.48
shop.harris-dindi.com.    IN A 192.18.2.48
```

It is then up to the server running on 192.18.2.48 to route requests to the correct application, for example by the mechanism of name based virtual hosts.